# Any way to do DISTINCT ON?

Tags: 7, database

I'm trying to create a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (field1, field2) field1, field2, field3 FROM table1
```

But can't figure out how to get DISTINCT ON narrowed down to a few fields in Drupal like that. Calling `$query->distinct()` just seems to structure the query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2, field3 FROM table1
```

I did figure out a hacky way to add what I want by adding an expression before I add any fields like this:

```
$query->addExpression('DISTINCT ON (field1, field2) field1', 'field1');
```

Which creates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (field1, field2) field1 as field1, field2, field3 FROM table1
```

I'm looking for a better way to this ?

Answer (score 3):

You could try with the [distinct()](https://drupal.org/node/1848354) method for dynamic queries and see how it goes with your query.

There is an [example](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.install/function/taxonomy_update_7005/7) to follow on the taxonomy module of the Drupal core, on the following line:

```
$node_types = db_select($revision_name)
->distinct()
->fields($revision_name, array('bundle'))
->execute()
->fetchCol();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have use this some time, Hope this will help you.

```
$result = db_query("SELECT node.uid AS node_uid, node.created AS node_created, COUNT(DISTINCT node.title) AS node_title, COUNT(DISTINCT field_data_body.body_value) AS field_data_body_body_value, COUNT(DISTINCT field_data_body.delta) AS field_data_body_delta, COUNT(DISTINCT field_data_body.language) AS field_data_body_language, COUNT(DISTINCT field_data_body.bundle) AS field_data_body_bundle, COUNT(DISTINCT field_data_body.body_summary) AS field_data_body_body_summary, COUNT(DISTINCT field_data_body.body_format) AS field_data_body_body_format
FROM 
{node} node")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should set that field on your query
something like

if you want distinct on 2 field

```
db_select('table1','t1')->fields('t1',array('field1','field2'))->distinct()->execute();
```

the query will be

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.field1 AS field1, t1.field2 AS field2 FROM {table1} t1
```

and for one field

```
db_select('table1','t1')->fields('t1',array('field1'))->distinct()->execute();
SELECT DISTINCT t1.field1 AS field1 FROM {table1} t1
```